A travelling magnet passing through a static ring magnet, overall net acceleration question
If I have a magnet travelling through empty space, and it passes through a static (infinite mass for all intents and purposes) ring magnet, in such a way that it is being attracted towards the ring as it approaches it, and also attracted (pulled back) towards the ring as it's leaving after passing through. And we say its starting position is Y meters from the ring magnet, and starting velocity is X. Would the travelling magnet accelerate approaching and decelerate leaving the ring by the same amount  and end up still with velocity X once it's Y meters past the ring on the other side? Or would the final velocity of the travelling magnet at Y meters past the ring be slightly higher than X, as it spends more time approaching the ring magnet and accelerating for longer than it spends decelerating after having passed through, as it is at that moment travelling quicker?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
